# Circular Gradients in CSS3

Tags: css

I'm looking to recreate a background like the one linked [here](http://www.desktopedia.com/bulkupload/Backgrounds/part2/Plain%20Blak%20Gray.jpg) using only css, I'm sure it's possible but I'm terrible at making CSS3 work for me.

If possible it should work in all modern browsers, not overly fussed about < IE8 support.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. The page you've linked to redirects to www.desktopedia.com, not the image; 2. What have you already tried? 3. Check out http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/.

Comment: I use colorzilla too, works fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the CSS to create a `Circular Gradient`.

Creating gradient using CSS3 is very easy now. As there are many tools available.
Here are some online tools generate the gradiend code:

[Colorzilla Gradients](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

[Gradientoo](http://gradientoo.com/)

```
div{  
    width:250px;
    height: 250px;
     background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, #ffeda3, #ffc800);
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, #ffeda3, #ffc800);
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, #ffeda3, #ffc800);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, #ffeda3, #ffc800);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle cover, #ffeda3, #ffc800);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffeda3', endColorstr='#ffc800',GradientType=1 ); 
}
```

Here is the Demo. http://jsbin.com/wedubinu/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #1e5799 0%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

Generated by http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/